# Storing MySQL data in an image file (formatted as ext4)

Tags: docker, mariadb

I'm trying to use Docker to containerize a MySQL (MariaDB actually) database. I figured out how to store MySQL data (/var/lib/mysql) in a volume mounted from a host directory.

However, because the underlying filesystem is different from host to host there are some inconsistencies, for example table names are case insensitive on NTFS (Windows). Also, it looks like if the database is created on a Linux host it doesn't work on a Windows host (haven't figured out why exactly).

Therefore, I want to store the data on a disk image and mount it inside the container, i.e. `db-data.img` formatted as ext4. But I'm facing a strange problem, when mounting this image inside the container:

```
$ docker run -v $PWD:/outside --rm -it ubuntu /bin/bash
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/test.img bs=1M count=100
# mkfs.ext4 test.img
# mount -o loop -t ext4 test.img /mnt
mount: /mnt: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
```

Using another directory instead of `/mnt` didn't work either.

Why does it refuse to mount the img file?

Comment: `$` implies that you are not running as `root`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the `privileged` option in docker-compose.yml:

```
privileged: true
```

(or `--privileged` in the docker command)

Here is my final docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build: ./db
    image: my_db
    container_name: db
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_IMG}:/data.img
    restart: always
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mariadb

COPY my-custom.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf

COPY run.sh /usr/local/bin/run-mariadb.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["run-mariadb.sh"]
```

and a custom entry point script that executes `mount` (run.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

# For this mount comamnd to work the DB container must be started
# with --privileged.
mount -o loop /data.img /var/lib/mysql

# Call the entry point script of MariaDB image.
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `docker-compose` and just use a volume declared in the `docker-compose.yml` configuration.

Something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
            MYSQL_PASS: $MYSQL_PASSWORD
        volumes:
            - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    mysql-data:
```

The `mysql-data` volume should be stored as a separate volume, independent from the host operating system. The difference to just mounting a directory on the host, it's basically mounting a volume container (which you could also do without *docker-compose*, but it's more work).

Answer (score 0):

It will not work inside of docker image, Docker blocks access to mouning filesystems (and loop devices). Should be easier create these image earlier, mount and connect to docker as folder by `-v`.

P.S. Another option is dump your database to sql and restore from windows.

Answer (score 0):

for storing database data make docker-compose.yml will look like
if you want to use Dockerfile

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

your docker-compose.yml will looks like
if you want to use your image instead of Dockerfile

```
version: '3.1'   

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
volumes:
```

if you want to store or preserve data of mysql then
must remember to add two lines in your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

after that use this command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

now your data will persistent and will not be deleted even after using this command

```
docker-compose down
```

extra:- but if you want to delete all data then you will use

```
docker-compose down -v
```

plus you can check your data list by this command

```
docker volume ls

DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               35c819179d883cf8a4355ae2ce391844fcaa534cb71dc9a3fd5c6a4ed862b0d4
local               133db2cc48919575fc35457d104cb126b1e7eb3792b8e69249c1cfd20826aac4
local               483d7b8fe09d9e96b483295c6e7e4a9d58443b2321e0862818159ba8cf0e1d39
local               725aa19ad0e864688788576c5f46e1f62dfc8cdf154f243d68fa186da04bc5ec
local               de265ce8fc271fc0ae49850650f9d3bf0492b6f58162698c26fce35694e6231c
local               phphelloworld_mysql-data
```